# Output to a file when console output is available

Tags: bash, terminal

I know how to write output to a file, with `>` to write and repalce or `>>` to write and append, but I need to know how exec a command when the main program has output.

Being specific, I want to save the date and time of each printout in a file, how can I do it?

I try some like that:

`./program_out | date >> fileout`

but date is executed only one time.

Comment: `{ ./program_out; date; } >> file.out`

Comment: If you want the realtime date and time of every output line in the log, you might want to look at the solution provided here (https://serverfault.com/questions/310098/how-to-add-a-timestamp-to-bash-script-log).